# What is the significance of player wage in player career mode?

Tags: fifa-14

When playing in career player mode, there is a wage figure that is shown. Does it matter how much you get? Does it affect gameplay in any way (other than maybe higher targets from the manager)?

Also, I see different wage values through My Actions and My Career interfaces, even though the player value is the same. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

It does not make a gameplay difference for player career mode, and its' use is predominantly as an indicator to you on just how valuable your player has become.

People feel good about the fact that they are playing well enough for clubs to pay millions for them.

Answer (score -2):

by increasing wages of your player after intervals makes the morale of player happy towards the club  and increases the value of the player